# Cannot send message to local JMS Queue over default Artemis/ActiveMQ in Wildfly 10

Tags: configuration, jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis

Using Wildfly 10.1.0.Final and a custom JMS message queue, I can successfully send and receive messages over the in-vm `InVmConnectionFactory` with the JNDI name `java:/ConnectionFactory`.

However, I cannot get the new `pooled-connection-factory` with JNDI name `java:/JmsXA` to work, messages simply get lost and don't show up anywhere (also checked the wildfly console's runtime JMS server view (`Runtime->Subsystems->Messaging - ActiveMQ`).

Because the `active-mq` pooled connection factory is marked as `DefaultJMSConnectionFactory`, using the JMS 2.0 API and simply injecting the JMSContext via

```
@Inject
JmsContext jmsContext;
```

message sending *will not work* out of the box.

This is quite strange and I have found no similar issues with a recent wildfly 10 configuration that uses the included Artemis (ActiveMQ) broker.

The connection-factory is defined as *transactional* by default, but this is overkill for our scenario, so I switched it off:

```
<pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA" connectors="in-vm" transaction="none"/>
```

I checked the [Wildfly messaging configuration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Messaging+configuration) and various online examples covering JMS 1.1/2.0, but found no clue so far.

Sample code:

```
@Startup  // just for a simple test sending a message right on startup
public class MessageService {

    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("java:/JmsXA")  // activemq-ra pooled-connection-factory
    private JMSContext jmsContext;

    @Resource(lookup = JAVA_JMS_PROGRESS_QUEUE)
    private Queue progressQueue;

    public MessageService() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        final JMSProducer jmsProducer = jmsContext.createProducer();
        jmsProducer.send(progressQueue, "Hello queue"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out the method where the message is sent *still needs* to be declared as non-transactional, even when the connection-factory is already configured as such:

```
@PostConstruct
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
private void init() {
...
```

works now!